# what is the Syntax for generic type parameter(in front of a function type)

Tags: typescript

I ever did some projects in TypeScript, however when I recently read a project code, I saw some declaration like below:

```
export interface SomeInterface<T> {
  <R>(paths: string[]): Observable<R>;
  <R>(Fn: (state: T) => R): Observable<R>;
}
```

I am not sure what is that syntax in TS for `<R>` which appears in front of a function typing like: `(paths: string[]) : Observable<R>`. If anyone have ideas on it, could you give me some clues on it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

That `<R>` is basically saying that the implementations of that interface must have a generic method with `<R>`. For example, for

`<R>(paths: string[]): Observable<R>`

a valid method that matches that prototype is:

```
function foo<R>(paths: string[]): Observable<R> {
  // function code here
}
```

Comment: I agree. Another explanation is that the user can choose the return type (or return type cast) of a function directly without using the class or interface based generic type.

Comment: Thank you, David. Two clarification I need additionally, I posted it( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45551455/does-this-interface-syntax-define-a-function-signature), would you help clarify.

Answer (score -1):

It's just generic.

Putting it on the function means it is only relevant to the function itself and not the whole interface.