# Does this Interface syntax define a function signature

Tags: typescript

I saw some code like below:

```
export interface SomeInterface<T> {
    <R>(paths: string[]): Observable<R>;
    <R>(Fn: (state: T) => R): Observable<R>;
}
```

I searched over TS documentation, but seems not find a good explanation. So I would like to ask:

1. where is the documentation for the usage for that `<R>`
2. Does the that kind of interface define a function with either one of those two signatures? Is my understanding correct? If that is, where is the documentation for it.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your understanding of the *intention* of the code is correct in that it's trying to define an interface for a set of functions that produce `Observable<R>`. However, while the interface is valid, I don't think any function could ever satisfy this interface's requirements because it has to *simultaneously* satisfy both of the function signatures. For a concrete example, try pasting the following into the [typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/)

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
    <R>(paths: string[]): Observable<R>;
    <R>(func: (state: T) => R): Observable<R>;
}

interface Observable<T> {
    someField: T;
}

let createObservableFromPaths = (paths: string[]): Observable<string[]> => {
    return { someField: paths };
}

let func: SomeInterface<string> = createObservableFromPaths;
```

You'll get the following error from the compiler:

```
Types of parameters 'paths' and 'func' are incompatible.
  Type '(state: string) => any' is not assignable to type 'string[]'.
    Property 'push' is missing in type '(state: string) => any'.
```

To make this work, you'll need to split `SomeInterface<T>` into two separate generic function interfaces.

Comment: It's just an overloaded function.  You can certainly implement it.

Answer (score 2):

The usage of type parameters in a call signature is documented [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#3921-type-parameters).

The interface describes an [overloaded function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads).  It needs to implement *both* signatures.  You can* do this like so:

```
function f<R>(paths: string[]): Observable<R>;  // not really possible
function f<R>(func: (state: number) => R): Observable<R>;
function f<R>(something: string[] | ((state: number) => R)): Observable<R> {
  if (Array.isArray(something)) {
    return { someField: null as any as R }; // see? can't do it!
  }
  return { someField: something(2) };
}
const someInterfaceNumber: SomeInterface<number> = f;
```

This compiles fine.  Hope that helps!

---

<sub>*okay, you actually *can't* really do this, but that's just because the first signature says that it is a generic function which takes a `string[]` parameter and outputs an `Observable<R>` for any `R` the caller wants... which can't be done.  You don't have any object of type `R` to return.  So you can fake it up (`null as any as R`), but I'd be concerned about anyone trying to use that interface.</sub>

Comment: I think Michael's answer is more precise, this kind of interface cannot be used as a type annotation for a function type variable. When compiling, ts give you error message. But it is so helpful to me that you provide the documentation link for that kind of type parameter which appears in front of a function signature.

Comment: I have shown you above how you can indeed create a value of the interface type.  It is the signature of an overloaded function, and @MichaelWu is not correct to say it is impossible.  All he showed was that he did not implement it, not that it couldn't be implemented.